# Sorting Algorithms Optimisation Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded

```
def MinimumSwaps(Queue):
        MinSwaps = 0
        for i in range(len(Queue) - 1):
            if Queue[i] != i+1:
                for j in range(i+1,len(Queue)):
                    if Queue[j] == i+1:
                        Queue[i], Queue[j] = Queue[j], Queue[i]
                        MinSwaps += 1
                        break
            else:
                continue
        return MinSwaps

def main():
    Result = MinimumSwaps([7, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6])
    print(Result)  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**The question**: You are given an unordered array consisting of consecutive integers  [1, 2, 3, ..., n] without any duplicates. You are allowed to swap any two elements. You need to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the array in ascending order.

The issue is that what I have provided is inefficient and fails on very large arrays, however Ive tried to optimise it as much as I can and im not aware of another technique to use. This question is likely related to a particular sorting algorithm but is there any way to modify the above code to make it faster?

Comment: how large is n?

Comment: 100,000 is the max.

Comment: Unordered array of consecutives..?

Comment: Yes, just consider it a randomised array of integers that were originally consecutive. But it was described as I posted in the question. An example is given in the main() function.

Comment: Is the input a Queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of *searching* for the value that belongs at `Queue[i]` to swap it there, just swap the value that *is* there to where that belongs:

```
def MinimumSwaps(Queue):
    MinSwaps = 0
    for i in range(len(Queue) - 1):
        while Queue[i] != i + 1:
            j = Queue[i] - 1
            Queue[i], Queue[j] = Queue[j], Queue[i]
            MinSwaps += 1
    return MinSwaps
```

This improves the performance to \$O(1)\$ for using a value instead of the \$O(n)\$ for searching. And thus total performance to \$O(n)\$ instead of your original \$O(n^2)\$. Still using only O(1) extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is \$O(n^2)\$ because of the inner loop.

> ```py
> for j in range(i+1,len(Queue)):
>     if Queue[j] == i+1:
>        # inner
> ```

We can change this to be \$O(1)\$ by making a lookup table of where \$i\$'s location is.
We can build a dictionary to store these lookups.

```py
indexes = {value: index for index, value in enumerate(Queue)
```

We can then just swap these indexes with your existing inner code to get \$O(n)\$ performance.

```py
def MinimumSwaps(Queue):
    indexes = {value: index for index, value in enumerate(Queue)}
    MinSwaps = 0
    for i in range(len(Queue) - 1):
        i_value = Queue[i]
        if i_value != i+1:
            j = indexes[i+1]
            j_value = Queue[j]
            Queue[i], Queue[j] = Queue[j], Queue[i]
            indexes[i_value], indexes[j_value] = indexes[j_value], indexes[i_value]
            MinSwaps += 1
        else:
            continue
    return MinSwaps
```

There is potentially performance on the table by using a dictionary as a lookup table rather than a list. Whilst both have the same algorithmic complexity. To address this we can just build `indexes` as a list.

```py
indexes = [None] * len(Queue)
for index, value in enumerate(Queue):
    indexes[value] = index
```

Comment: Why this answer get downvoted? It may not be the best idea. But it at least works (boost the performance by reducing the big-O time complexity of original code).

Comment: @tsh Another user has taken a quite unhealthy dislike to me. So downvoted straight after seeing who posted the answer. The second, IDK. As you say the answer answered the question by improving the performance of the code, could my answer be poorly worded or something? IDK. Speculating probably isn't a good idea unless I get a couple more downvotes. So in the mean time I'll just assume [Tim lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397).

Comment: @tsh I see the OP's way as going in the wrong direction (solving *towards* the current list spot instead of the simpler and faster *away* from the current list spot) and thus this solution as *running* in the wrong direction, with even *more complicated* code and less space-efficiency. Plus just recently they [made a fuss](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/255575/determine-the-longest-segment-of-integers-within-an-inclusive-range-that-doesnt/255580#comment504340_255580) about set operations being O(n) instead of O(1), which they then should've done here for the dict as well.

Comment: @superbrain "which they then should've done here" I did, look at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Where? You even explicitly say "We can change this to be O(1)".

Comment: "There is potentially performance on the table by using a dictionary as a lookup table rather than a list."

Comment: You must've forgotten your "Whilst both have the same algorithmic complexity" directly following that.

Comment: @superbrain No, I've not forgotten that. To many they do have the same algorithmic complexity, and my answer is targeted to the level of the asker where they do. It's like when a teacher teaches that "there are three states of matter" when _that's obviously a lie_. A large part of teaching is not being 100% right it's about expanding the capabilities of the student without overwhelming them.

Comment: It shows that that "performance on the table" refers to the constant factor that one would expect between dict and list, so you can't seriously consider that pointing out the O(n) vs O(1) thing.

Comment: @superbrain Yeah, there is, as you've said, more than one reason that a list would be superior to a dictionary here. When I talk about "performance" there it arguably doesn't have much to do with Big-O. I'm pretty sure you know that performance and Big-O are very different in Python. I recall you got an \$O(n^2)\$ algorithm to be faster than an \$O(n)\$ one with `.index` or something. There are many reasons list is better than dict.

Comment: @superbrain I would agree that there are better ways to archive the task. But... The upvote button suggests "this answer is useful" and downvote button suggests "this answer is not useful". Since OP tagged this question with [tag:time-limit-exceeded], and this post does boost the performance by reducing running time from \$O(n^2)\$ into \$O(n)\$. This answer may solve TLE issue. So it is definitely useful. It would be fair to upvote another answer (which is better) but not this one. But I don't think it is the reason to downvote this one. That's what I meant.

Comment: @tsh I appreciate your comment. I personally am fine with being downvoted for whatever reason superb rain has. "[It's normally recommended to vote on the quality of the post, not the user. And so some may disagree with your opinion if you change it because of the user. But these users have their own vote buttons that they can use.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9178)" - me from almost two years ago :)